# How to create a input range using plain javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, range

Is there any way to recreate the input range using plain js (without using jQuery).

### Expected Result

```html
<input type="range">
```

### My current work

```js
function slide(e,t) {
    t.style.paddingLeft = e.clientX-t.offsetLeft+'px';
}
```

```css
div {
    width : 400px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    margin: 20px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div>div {
    height: 10px;
    width : 10px;
    background-color: black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    transform: translate(-10%, -10%);
}
```

```html
<div onclick="slide(event,this)" onmouseover="slide(event,this)">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

### Problem

In an actual input range the thumb only moves when we are dragging it but here it moves when we are hovering over it. is there any way to move it when we are only dragging it ?. Even in an example with many sliders in the same page.

Any help in rephrasing the question is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you doing this? [All modern browsers support `<input type="range">` already, so there's no need to recreate it in JavaScript](https://caniuse.com/input-range). Heck, even _Internet Explorer 10_ supports it...

Comment: @Dai the purpose is purely educational.

Comment: If you're wanting to learn how to properly handle `touch*` and `mousemove` events, there are much better exercises than a `range` input, imo. Have you considered starting off with something simpler, such as a `<canvas>` painting demo?

Comment: @Dai Thanks for your recommendation. 'll look in to that. :)

Comment: @Dai I agree that slider is supported nowadays, but it's not that straigthforward to style, or to have different types of reaction to mouse moving or touch, so it's not such a bad exercise.

Comment: @AHaworth I think it's a very bad idea to try to reimplement basic user input controls though, when you consider the breadth of devices users use and accessibility concerns. To reimplement the `range` input _properly_ would take weeks (consider `aria-`, having to re-design 3 times over for `fine`, `coarse`, and `none` touch input devices, accessibility, screen-reader support, internationalization/globalization/localization of how numeric values are handled, snapping-to-points, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what u wanted?

```js
function slide(e,t) {
    t.children[0].style.paddingLeft = e.clientX-t.offsetLeft+'px';
}
```

```css
div {
  position:relative;
  width: 400px;
  max-width:400px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
/*   margin: 20px 0; */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div > div {
/*   position: absolute; */
  top: -2px;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  background-color: #0075FF;
  border: 1px solid black;
/*   transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
  max-height: fit-content;
}

div > div:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #0075FF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -4px; 
  right: -4px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
Mouse Click only
<br>
<br>
<div onclick="slide(event,this)" >
    <div></div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
Mouse Move
<br>
<br>
<div onclick="slide(event,this)" onmousemove="slide(event,this)">
    <div></div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
Mouse Drag
<br>
<br>
<div onclick="slide(event,this)"  draggable="true" ondrag="slide(event,this)">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work OK, but some explanation of what you have done/changed would make your answer more valuable. Can you add some?

Answer (score 0):

Here would be an example of how to do it just when the mouse is pressed and the mouse moves:

```js
const slider = document.querySelector(".slider");

let mouseDown = false;

const setMouseDown = () => {
  mouseDown = !mouseDown;

  console.log(mouseDown);
}

slider.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", setMouseDown);

  slide(event);

  setMouseDown();
});

slider.addEventListener("mousemove", slide);

function slide(event) {
  if (mouseDown)
    this.style.paddingLeft = event.clientX - this.offsetLeft + 'px';
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  margin: 20px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div>div {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transform: translate(-10%, -10%);
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div></div>
</div>
```